# Receiving NaN when passing argument "0" to function

Tags: javascript, function, nan

I'm studying the javascript, and I had a result that I did not expect, I do not know where I'm going wrong, follow the testable example below:

```js
const createStore = () => ({
  state: {
    life: 100
  },
  mutations: {
    reduceOneOfLife(state) {
      state.life -= 1;
    },
    reduceValueOfLife(state, valueForReduce) {
      state.life -= valueForReduce;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    currentLife(state) {
      return state.life;
    }
  },
  commit(keyMutation, payload) {
    !payload ? this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state) : this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state, payload);
  },
  get(KeyGetters) {
    return this.getters[KeyGetters](this.state);
  }
});

const store = createStore();

store.mutations.reduceValueOfLife(store.state, 0);
let currentLife = store.get('currentLife');
console.log(currentLife); // -> 100
console.log(currentLife === 100); // -> true

store.commit('reduceValueOfLife', 10);
currentLife = store.get('currentLife');
console.log(currentLife); // -> 90
console.log(currentLife === 100); // -> false

store.commit('reduceValueOfLife', 0);
currentLife = store.get('currentLife');
console.log(currentLife); // -> NaN
console.log(currentLife === 90); // -> false
```

I expected to get **90** and **true** in the test `store.commit('reduceValueOfLife', 0);...`.

Comment: hint: `!payload` is `true` when `payload === 0` (or `false`, or `''` or `null` or `undefined` or `NaN` - I think that's all of them)

Comment: @JaromandaX I did not know, thought it was just for 'undefined'. what are all the cases that `!payload` would happen?

Comment: I listed them in the edit :p for the logic you're looking for, I'd suggest `(payload === undefined) ? ....`

Comment: @JaromandaX I just need to check if it's `undefined` anyway, thank the light. And I do not know, but I think it's a lack of education, the human being gets mad with any little power he receives.

Comment: another option is to check if `arguments.length < 2`

Comment: @JaromandaX this may be an even better solution to the issue, as this will not get in the way of getting some `undefined` value from some other code. You could make a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is because `0` is ("falsey") (along with `null`, `undefined`, `''`, `NaN` and of course `false`)

this means `this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state)` will be executed when passing in `0` as the second argument in

```
commit(keyMutation, payload) {
    !payload ? this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state) : this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state, payload);
},
```

While you could simply test if `payload === undefined` instead, that would mean that you can never pass in `undefined` as the payload

instead, you can check how many arguments the function has been called with using `arguments.length` like so:

```
commit(keyMutation, payload) {
    (arguments.length < 2) ? this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state) : this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state, payload);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `commit` function has:

```
commit(keyMutation, payload) {
    !payload ? this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state) : this.mutations[keyMutation]    (this.state, payload);
},
```

That is, the first expression only runs if `payload` is *truthy*. But your

```
store.commit('reduceValueOfLife', 0);
```

is calling with a *falsey* `payload` value, so the following runs:

```
this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state)
```

with `keyMutation` as `'reduceValueOfLife'`. So your `reduceValueOfLife` function

```
reduceValueOfLife(state, valueForReduce) {
        state.life -= valueForReduce;
        console.log('subtr ' + valueForReduce + ' --- ' + typeof valueForReduce);
}
```

gets called with `valueForReduce` as `undefined`, and subtracting `undefined` from whatever `state.life` originally was results in `NaN`.

Better to check whether `payload` is *undefined*, rather than just *falsey*, and then your the `store.get` returns a number value, rather than `NaN`:

```
commit(keyMutation, payload) {
  if (payload === undefined) this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state)
  else this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state, payload);
},
```

Another option for your `commit`, rather than checking whether arguments are defined, is to simply *call the `[keyMutation]` function with `this.state` and `payload`. If `commit`'s `payload` is `undefined`, then the second argument passed will be `undefined`, which is the same behavior you would see if you don't pass a second parameter at all.

```
commit(keyMutation, payload) {
  this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state, payload);
},
```

If you want the final `currentLife` to be 100, after it was reduced to 90 in the second part, then you'll have to call

```
store.commit('reduceValueOfLife', -10);
```

in the last part to increment it back up to 100:

```js
const createStore = () => ({
  state: {
    life: 100
  },
  mutations: {
    reduceOneOfLife(state) {
      state.life -= 1;
    },
    reduceValueOfLife(state, valueForReduce) {
      state.life -= valueForReduce;
      console.log('subtr ' + valueForReduce + ' --- ' + typeof valueForReduce);
    }
  },
  getters: {
    currentLife(state) {
      return state.life;
    }
  },
  commit(keyMutation, payload) {
    if (payload === undefined) this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state)
    else this.mutations[keyMutation](this.state, payload);
  },
  get(KeyGetters) {
    return this.getters[KeyGetters](this.state);
  }
});

const store = createStore();

store.mutations.reduceValueOfLife(store.state, 0);
let currentLife = store.get('currentLife');
console.log(currentLife); // -> 100
console.log(currentLife === 100); // -> true

store.commit('reduceValueOfLife', 10);
currentLife = store.get('currentLife');
console.log(currentLife); // -> 90
console.log(currentLife === 100); // -> false

store.commit('reduceValueOfLife', -10);
currentLife = store.get('currentLife');
console.log(currentLife);
console.log(currentLife === 100);
```

Comment: That part of "-10" runs away from the question, I have edited the question to address only the question problem.